# AdMob - my own impressions

Tags: c#, c++, java, android, ios

I wanted to test my in-game ads and I forgot to add my device as a `Test Device`. My game is not yet in Google Play and App Store but I have 12 impressions on AdMob. What I have to do in this situation? I know that Google bans for fake click and impression so what can I do? do I have to inform Google about that?

Thank for help.

Comment: did you try *contacting Google*?

Comment: It is near impossible to contact Google. A few impressions shouldn't matter because the cost for ads happens when somebody clicks the ad. Never click the ads. But you should set your device up as a test device to avoid the risk

Comment: Gnemlock: I tried contact AdMob but I could not find any contact adress.

Sys_Admin_Luddite: that's good, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't imagine that you'll get banned for just forgetting to add your device as a Test Device. Plenty of developers make this mistake; it's nothing to be worried about.

The rule against fake impressions is most likely just to prevent someone from sitting there for hours, clicking on every ad that they're presented, and just raking in money for fake impressions.

If your account hasn't been suspended or you haven't been contacted by AdMob, I don't think you need to worry about it. If anything does happen, you can just tell them that you forgot to add your device as a Test Device. From what I could tell from [AdMob's Help Center](https://support.google.com/admob/?hl=en#topic=2745287), **if your account is disabled for Invalid Click Activity**, you can repeal it at [this link.](https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/2707037)